# Debug "about:blank" in CasperJs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have the following simple casperjs script (I cannot name the actual URL - sorry) on a Windows 7 machine:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose:true,logLevel: "debug"});

casper.start('https://[XXX].de', function() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

The Output states that it failed - and the current url is : "about:blank"

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://[XXX].de, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://[XXX].de, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://[XXX].de
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
about:blank
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2: done in 39205ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 39309ms
```

When send a GET request with the Firefox RESTCLient Plugin - I get:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2012 11:09:37 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: unknown
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

My question is:

How can I debug this? Is this a known issue ?

Comment: I believe this could be an issue with the ssl certificate. But: `casperjs test.js  --ignore-ssl-errors=yes` returns "Error: Unknown option: casper-path" - Mmmh.

Comment: I tried with the latest casperjs version from github - now there `casperjs test.js --ignore-ssl-errors=yes` does not through an error - but the actual problem is still there (about:blank etc).

Comment: is your questing still troubling for you?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo no - i moved on ;)

Comment: i am not sure but looks like when `casper.close();` executed page moved to  about:blank

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the command line arguments passed to casperjs are not being passed to PhantomJS. I also ran into this issue and to fix this I ran my script as follows:

```
PhantomJS.exe --ignore-ssl-errors=true myscript.js
```

When I tried passing the parameters the other way around

```
PhantomJS.exe myscript.js --ignore-ssl-errors=true
```

it **does not work** and gives the same error as you have been facing.

Comment: This seems to be a known b0rk: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/49 on windows.

Comment: Thank you, if I specify option parameters first like this it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

To pass `phantomjs` parameters to `casperjs`, you can directly update your `casper` binary(`casperjs.py` on linux or `casperjs.bat` on windows).

On Linux, Open the `casperjs.py`, Update the `CASPER_COMMAND` array which is forming the `phantomjs` command and execute.

To add "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", extend the `CASPER_COMMAND` by the following,

```
CASPER_COMMAND.extend(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']);
```

For the same, on windows or For more info can be found [here](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/49)

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please consider code format in your answer. It takes 1 minute and it's helpful to identify code stuff in an easy way.